# "Unpermitted parameters: " in Rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build nested forms, where users can add one or multiple time slot for each invitation that they create.

in the `Invitations` view i have `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for invitation, id: "invitation_form", :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:guest_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, {}, class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose recipient", multiple: true) %>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.collection_select(:type_of_event, @type_evenement, :id, :type_name, {:include_blank => true}, class: "selectpicker", title: "Type", multiple: false) %>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <br>
      <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, @events_list, :id, :title, {:include_blank => true}, class: "selectpicker", title: "Related event (Optional)", multiple: false) %>
      <br>
      <br>
      <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Title", label: false %>
      <%= f.text_area :memo, placeholder: "Start writing", class: "form form-control", rows: 10 %>
      <div class="fields">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :invsession do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'invitations/invsession_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <br>
        <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

in the same Invitation view I have partial `_invsession_fields.html.erb`

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= f.input_field :_destroy, as: :hidden %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', class: 'remove_record' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
      <%= f.text_field :start, :class => "form-control" %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span><br>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
      <%= f.text_field :end, :class => "form-control" %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

in my `Invitation controller`:

```
  def new
        @type_evenement = TypeEvenement.all
        @invitation = current_user.invitations.build(invitation_params)
        @invitation.invsessions.build
  end


   def invitation_params
      params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id, :guest_id, :event_id, :start, :title, :type_of_event,:memo, :seen, :deleted, :modified, invsessions_attributes: Invsession.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy))
    end
```

My Invitation model :

```
class Invitation < ApplicationRecord    
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invsessions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invsessions, allow_destroy: true      
end
```

and my invsessions model:

```
class Invsession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invitation, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The display works well, but when i click save, it only save the new invitation, but not the new invsession item. I have the following:

```
Processing by InvitationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "invitation"=>{"guest_id"=>["", "1"], "type_of_event"=>"2", "event_id"=>"108", "title"=>"ssss", "memo"=>"ssss", "invsession"=>{"_destroy"=>"", "start"=>"2018-11-02 04:15 am +08:00", "end"=>"2018-11-02 04:15 am +08:00"}}, "commit"=>"Create Invitation", "locale"=>"en-us"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: :guest_id, :invsession
1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (23.0ms)  INSERT INTO "invitations" ("user_id", "guest_id", "event_id", "title", "memo", "created_at", "updated_at", "type_of_event") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["guest_id", 1], ["event_id", 108], ["title", "ssss"], ["memo", "ssss"], ["created_at", "2018-11-02 08:15:37.916159"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-02 08:15:37.916159"], ["type_of_event", 2]]
   (25.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

with this line that I do not know how to fix     `Unpermitted parameters: :guest_id, :invsession`

Is there something that should be modified for this to work? i am following a tutorial on drifting ruby (070) that seems pretty straight-forward.

Comment: i think you are not passing `guest_id` and `invsession` in `invitation_params`   method. can you share your `invitation_params`.

Comment: Hi Pardeep, I just added to the orginal poste, my `invitation_params`

Comment: I will restart the tutorial from scratch, nothing seems to work, and tried following all the recommendations I received.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that you have here is that the form isn't creating the correct name for the inputs you have there on the nested one.

you have different options here, remember that you are using simple_form to create the inputs, so, use the helper from simple_form to create the inputs and it will create the correct name auto-magically

```
<%= f.input :start, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

for this of course you need to config simple_form to adapt it for the structure you want for your input.

or in the other case if you just want to let things like this, set the name for the inputs manually like this.

```
 <%= f.text_field :start, :class => "form-control", name: 'invitation[invsession_attributes][start]' %>
```

this will create the needed structure for the params on your form and will come inside `invsession_attributes` because that's the one you are using on the permited params method.

Comment: Hi @xploshioOn, I used the second method and get the following:
...`"HJH", "memo"=>"HJHJHJ", "invsession"=>{"_destroy"=>""}, "invsession_attributes"=>{"start"=>"2018-11-23 06:23 am +08:00", "end"=>"2018-11-23 06:23 am +08:00"}}, "commit"=>"Create Invitation", "locale"=>"en-us"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: :guest_id, :invsession, :invsession_attributes`

I think we are not far, just a matter of names to get right.

Comment: That's correct, you need to change the name for all the inputs inside the nested form. Not just the one I showed you

Comment: There are only 2 input actually, I changed both and got the above error message.

Comment: you need to add it to the destroy input too

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry to ask, but how do I do it please? it is the 1st time that I use this destroy input.

Comment: `    <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', class: 'remove_record', name: 'invitation[invsession_attributes][_destroy]' %>` this way ?

Comment: Just let it like it was before and add the name attribute

Answer (score -1):

Your `invitation_params` must be looks like this. According to this it will accept `guest_id` and `invsessions_attributes` as `Array` .

```
def invitation_params
  params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id, guest_id:[], :type_of_event, :event_id, :title, :memo, :seen, :deleted, :modified, invsessions_attributes: %i[_destroy start end])
end
```

you are using `nested_attributes` with `has_many` relationship so these attributes also received as array.

**#update 2**

can you please try this

```
def invitation_params
  params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id, guest_id:[], :type_of_event, :event_id, :title, :memo, :seen, :deleted, :modified, :invsessions_attributes => [:_destroy, :start, :end])
end
```

**#update 3**

```
def invitation_params
 params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id, :type_of_event, :event_id, :title, :memo, :seen, :deleted, :modified, guest_id:[], :invsessions_attributes => [:_destroy, :start, :end])
end
```

putting `guest_id:[]` before `invsessions_attributes` works.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey, I made the change and get the following error now:

`SyntaxError (/Users/Test/app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:120: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...it(guest_id:[], :type_of_event, :event_id, :title, :memo, in...
...                              ^
/Users/Test/app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:120: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...ributes: %[_destroy start end])
...                              ^
/Users/Test/app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end)`

Comment: The thing is the Invitations were being created perfectly. The only issue is the creation of the invsessions.

Comment: forgot add `,` after `:modified`. now added. rest of things works fine.

Comment: one more thing you are using `end` for storing end date of invsesson but this is reserved keyword in ruby. This may cause error. It is recommended to change `start` with `start_date`  and `end` with `end_date`.

Comment: @PardeepSaini: "rest of things works fine" - no, it doesn't. This will still fail to load with a parse error.

Comment: `SyntaxError (/Users/Test/app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:120: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...d, guest_id:[], :type_of_event, :event_id, :title, :memo, :s...
...                              ^
/Users/Test/app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:120: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...ibutes: %i[_destroy start end])
...                              ^
/Users/Test/app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end):`

Comment: `app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:120: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:120: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: Hey, i just checked. But why "params.require(:user)", why "user" i mean ?

Comment: my mistake i just testing it in my code. replaced `:user` with `:invitation`

Comment: ok, no pb, I did, and I get  the following :
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "invitation"=>{"guest_id"=>["", "12"], "type_of_event"=>"6", "event_id"=>"125", "title"=>"Catch", "memo"=>"catch", "invsession"=>{"_destroy"=>"", "start"=>"2018-11-16 06:22 am +08:00", "end"=>"2018-11-16 07:22 am +08:00"}}, "commit"=>"Create Invitation", "locale"=>"en-us"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]`
Unpermitted parameter: :invsession` something still wrong with invsession for some reason.

Comment: actually you are sending invsession params wrong way. it must be like this `{"utf8"=>"✓", "invitation"=>{"guest_id"=>["", "12"], "type_of_event"=>"6", "event_id"=>"125", "title"=>"Catch", "memo"=>"catch", "invsessions_attributes"=>[{"_destroy"=>"", "start"=>"2018-11-16 06:22 am +08:00", "end"=>"2018-11-16 07:22 am}] +08:00"}}, "commit"=>"Create Invitation", "locale"=>"en-us"}`. if you want to use nested attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183000/discussion-between-pardeep-saini-and-etienne).